# build xml and build-impl.xml in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have java project in `Netbeans` that builds fine and places `myproject.jar` file to dist directory. And that is fine.

I decided to copy authomatically `myproject.jar` to another directory after build is done. I edited `build.xml` by placing lines

```
<target name="-post-compile">   
<copy file="dist/myproject.jar" tofile="c:/anotherLocation/myproject.jar"/>
</target>
```

And now I have warning:

```
Warning: Could not find file C:\projectLocation\dist\myproject.jar to copy.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

And `dist` directory is not created untill I have removed new lines in `build.xml`.

How to have both features - build and copy?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for

```
<target name="-post-jar">`
```

If you check the commentary section inside the `build.xml`, you can see that:

```
-post-compile:             called after javac compilation <-- .class files created
-post-jar:                 called after JAR building      <-- .jar file created
```

before `-post-jar`, there is no `.jar` file yet, so a warning is called.